# import a less file with global variable has strange behavior

Tags: webpack, less

I have 4 less files:

**test.less**

```
@import "./test-a.less";
@import "./test-b.less";
@import "./test-c.less";
body {
  color: @globalVar;
}
```

**test-a.less**

```
@globalVar: red;
.a {
    color: @globalVar;
}
```

**test-b.less**

```
@globalVar: green;
.b {
    color: @globalVar;
}
```

**test-c.less**

```
.c {
    @import "./test-a.less";
    color: @globalVar;
}
```

I use webpack, [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader) and [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to compile those less into a single css file. I expect the output of .c should be like this because I'm importing the test-a.less in it but the output is completely make no sense to me. Can anyone explain it for me or show me a way to achieve what I want?

**Expected output to contains this block**

```
.c{ color: red; }
```

**Actual output**

```
.a {
  color: green;
}
.b {
  color: green;
}
.c {
  color: green;
}
body {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Subsequent imports of the same file are ignored by default - see http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Thank you, that default option took me few good hours. I believe your comment answered my question. You can post it as an answer and I'll mark this question resolved. If you won't post it as an answer, I'll quote it and answer myself in the next 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @seven-phases-max

> Subsequent imports of the same file are ignored by default - see lesscss.org/features/#import-options

I manage to resolve my problem by using **multiple** option

```
.c {
    @import (multiple) "./test-a.less";
    color: @globalVar;
}
```